# Devise stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, stack, stack-overflow

**After install Devise** I try to run

```
**rake db:migrate**
```

but it gives:

```
**rake aborted!
stack level too deep**
```

I'm on Ubuntu, changed

```
**ulimit -s unlimited**
```

and checked, it works, but still have the error.

I use **RVM**, tried to work out with *Ruby1.9.2-p180, Ruby-1.9.2-p0*, with **Rails 3.0.9, Rails 3.1rc4,** with Rubinius. 
Tried with **SQLite3 and with PostgreSQL.**
Tried to uncomment as many as I can from the migration file.

Read all related Stackoverflow posts (and realized what I have is actually named StackOverflow).

Any help would be highly appriaciated! Many thanks

Comment: Might help to post your migration file and anything that might be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stack level too deep errors typically result from infinite recursion problems.

New Answer:

I forgot this was occurring during db:migrate.  Is something in your users table migration relying on something that would rely on it?

Old Answer:

It would be helpful for you to show the lines of code you have in your routes.rb file for devise.  For example, you might have:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registration/foo" }
```

In this example, take a look at the new method in foo_controller.rb.  If that method redirects to another controller that causes you to attempt to register again, you will have an infinite recursion.

The first thing I would do is look at what controllers are being called by putting some sort of debug output in your controllers.  Try:

```
logger.debug("i am in foo")
```

or

```
puts "i am in bar"
```

If you can provide more information, I may be able to help more.

Comment: Perfect, so many thanks Larry, I'm really glad you saved my week. All problems solved with Devise now, you're right, it was kind of infinite loop: root redirecting to users/sign_in. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes, solved with first post, made self-reference. anyway thx for help.